# ImportError importing ssl in MinGW-W64 Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, mingw, pyopenssl

I've used MSYS2 to install the MinGW-W64 version of Python 3.6 (`mingw-w64-x86_64-python3`). Upon importing `ssl`, an `ImportError` is raised:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.2 (default, Aug 15 2017, 10:59:43)  [GCC 7.1.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "G:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.6\ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>>
```

I'm not sure why this. `pacman` shows both `mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl` and `openssl` as installed. `/mingw64/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl-cpython-36m.dll` exists. Other `.dll` files from the same directory (like those used for the `json` and `sqlite3` modules) import fine.

To make matters weirder, the Python 2 version (`mingw-w64-x86_64-python2`) doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I ran into the very same issue.  I reported it here: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/3381

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct solution (the MSYS2 folks are working on the real solution), but as a temporary workaround for anyone else who gets stuck on this:

After installing `mingw-w64-x86_64-python3` copy

- `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\LIBEAY32.dll` and
- `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\SSLEAY32.dll`

  to
- `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.6\lib-dynload\LIBEAY32.dll` and
- `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.6\lib-dynload\SSLEAY32.dll` respectively.

Afterwards `import ssl` (and tools that rely on it, like `pip3`) should work correctly.